# What's wrong with this bubble-sort function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, bubble-sort

I have my array defined but at the moment i go into implement my bubble sorting function it doesn't enter the first for loop. It does run the function however

```
function bubbleSort (){

    for (var j=0; j++; j < valores.length){
        for (var i=j+1; i++; i < valores.length){
            if (valores[j]>valores[i]){
                var temp=0
                temp=valores[j]
                valores[i]=valores[j]
                valores[j]=temp
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(valores)
}
```

so if valores input [2,1] I expect the output in console log to be [1,2].

I obtain my array by this function if that is of any help:

```
let valores =[];
let papelero=10;
function agregarValor (){

    if (valores.length < papelero){

        let val = Number(valor.value)

        valores.push(val)

        console.log(valores)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your for loop is incorrect `for (var j=0; j++; j < valores.length)` should read `for (var j=0; j < valores.length; j++)` also goes for the inner for loop

Comment: for (var j=0; j<valores.length; j++){
        for (var i=j+1; i<valores.length; j++) so it should look like this ? spoiler it didn't work

Comment: Where is `valor` defined in your `agregarValor` function?

Comment: @prieber 'let valor=document.getElementById('valor')'

Comment: <div class="col-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text"
                    class="form-control" name="" id="valor" aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="Valor">
                </div>
            </div>

Comment: @DavidRomero Well im trying not to spoil all of it, but your question seemed to be specifically "bubble sorting function it doesn't enter the first for loop" You have other issues within the loop such as your swap is incorrect.

Comment: @ug_ My apologies I am new to this platform, like I said it runs the function because i can use console log outside the loops and see the output.

Comment: I personally dont like answering questions which are homework with exact soultions. But what I can tell you is to take a step back and start debugging. Place a `console.log(valores[j], valores[i])` inside the inner most loop, watch the output and add things back in until you have whats expected. Drop the length of 10 array down to `[2,3,1]` fixed value and observe the interaction. Debugging is one of the most critical skills in programming

Comment: I did debug (kind of) using console.log in all the loops and that's why i noticed it didn't go even into the first one. My teachers here are pretty useless she din't know what was wrong with it. Thanks for your tip! I greatly appreciate it @ug_

Comment: @ug_ if figured it out. i didn't notice my swap was incorrect because i was reading j as i in my head rookie error. thanks for the help i truly appreciate it, that and the increments were wrong as you also said. in my second loop i was somehow incrementing j again instead of i. I really do appreciate the help :)

Comment: @DavidRomero Nice job! Yeah those `j` and `i` are hard to read. I prefer `k` instead of `j` just for that reason.

Comment: @ug_ oh yes that's perfect for future prpjects ! thanks again for the help I posted the answer down below if you want to copy and post it yourself to get the credit you deserve. i will delete mine afterwards :)

Comment: @DavidRomero Nope thats all you, thanks for coming back and answering your question for future users to see.

Answer (score 1):

like @ug_ said my swap was incorrect, and he previously said j and i were incremented in the wrong places.

```
function bubbleSort() { 
    for (var j=0; j<valores.length; j++) {
        for (var i=j+1; i<valores.length; i++) {
            if (valores[j]>valores[i]) {
                var temp=0
                temp=valores[i]
                valores[i]=valores[j]
                valores[j]=temp
             }
        }
    }
    console.log(valores)
}
```